# TypeError: 'HtmlResponse' object is not iterable

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm new to python, but trying to get my head around it in order to use Scrapy for work.

I'm currently following this tutorial:
http://scrapy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

I've having trouble with this part (from the tutorial):

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
        title = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        link = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        desc = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
        print title, link, desc
```

The problem I'm having is with the `for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):` part. I understand that line to essentially narrow down what is crawled to anything that matches the xpath `//ul/li`.

However, in my implementation, I can't narrow down the page to one singular section. I tried to get around this by selecting the entire HTML, see my attempt below:

```
   def parse(self, response):
           for sel in response.xpath('//html'):
            title = sel.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()
            author = sel.xpath('//head/meta[@name="author"]/@content').extract()
            mediumlink = sel.xpath('//head/link[@rel="author"]/@href').extract()
            print title, author, mediumlink
```

The xpaths work both in a Chrome plugin I use, and using `response.xpath('//title').extract()` in `scrapy shell`

I've tried changing the line to this:

`for sel in response.xpath('//html'):` and `for sel in response.xpath('html'):`

But each time I get this:

```
2016-10-16 14:33:43 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://medium.com/swlh/how-our-app-went-from-20-000-day-to-2-day-in-revenue-d6892a2801bf#.smmwwqxlf> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 587, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/Matthew/Sites/crawl/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/medium_Spider.py", line 11, in parse
    for sel in response:
TypeError: 'HtmlResponse' object is not iterable
```

Could somebody give me some pointers on how best to resolve this? Go easy on me, my skills are not so hot. Thanks!

Comment: There's only one `<html>` node, it's not iterable

Comment: Any suggestions on what to try?

Comment: The code you show and the error message are not consistent. According to the error message you are trying to iterate over `response`, not `response.xpath(...)`.

Comment: Note that this is the latest tutorial: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Comment: You can use [`response.selector`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse.selector) if you need to extract from the response directly, for example to extract the single title of a page. `for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li')` is used when you have multiple repeating items

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states

```
 for sel in response:
```

You try to iterate through the `response` object in your `medium_Spider.py` file at **line 11**.

However `response` is an `HtmlResponse` not an *iterable* which you could use in a `for` loop --> you are missing some method call on `response`. Try to do the loops as you have written in your question:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//html'):
```

Where `.xpath('//html')` returns an iterable which you can use in the `for` loop.